# Using if template equals in a WordPress function

Tags: wordpress

I am working with this function:

```
if ( $id && $post && $post->post_type == 'business-areas' ) 
{
  $pieces = explode(' ', $the_title);
  $last_word = trim(strtolower(array_pop($pieces)));

  if($last_word != 'jobs')
  {
    $the_title = $the_title . ' jobs';
  }
}

return $the_title;
```

This is basically appending the word JOBS to any titles on a custom post type of business-areas if the last word of the title is not JOBS.

Is there a way to add a template query to this?

So basically, if the page template of the custom post is DEFAULT, do this, if the page template is not DEFAULT, don't do it.

Comment: Do you want to change or check page title or post title or site title?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the `functions.php` file.

```
function add_label_to_post_title( $the_title = '' ) {
           global $post;
           if ($post && $post->post_type == 'business-areas' ) 
            {
              $pieces = explode(' ', $the_title);
              $last_word = trim(strtolower(array_pop($pieces)));

              if($last_word != 'jobs')
              {
                $the_title = $the_title . ' jobs';
              }
            }

            return $the_title;      
    }
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_label_to_post_title' );
```

Comment: Thanks for that - for some reason, it's also adding the JOBS text after all the menu items on the page?

Comment: Can you explain your question?

Comment: I have the function as above that appends the word jobs to any title on the custom post type of business-areas that does not end in jobs. We've enabled this custom post type to allow child pages - so basically I want the above to work if the page is a parent, but NOT if it's a child page within the same CPT.